# How to manage svn repositories in xcode

Tags: svn, xcode

I am using svn for my xcode project. I added two files to my current project, added them to the repository and commited changes for my classes folder. But when I try to commit the entire project, I get this error:

> Error: 155005 (Working copy not locked; this is probably a bug, please report) Description: Commit failed (details follow):
>   Error: 155005 (Working copy not locked; this is probably a bug, please report) Description: Directory '/Users/gopalmadhu/Desktop/All My data/Schduler current code/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/scheduler.app.dSYM/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing

Due to this, the classes that are already checked in do not become visible when I check my code out. The files are in the project, but not visible. As a workaround, I need to add them again from the project folder to the classes folder. This is not the correct way of managing svn. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean with "commit the entire project"? You should only ever commit source code and resources, not build files.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem is in committing build results to Subversion.

Subversion works by putting a hidden folder called .svn in every folder that is under version control.  This does not work well with folders that might get deleted and recreated by a tool because the tool will probably not respect the existence of the .svn folder.  That includes the whole build directory, the contents of which get wiped every time you clean your project targets.

You should remove your build directory from version control.  It shouldn't be in there anyway since everything in it can be regenerated by doing an Xcode build.  To get out of your existing dilemma try the following:

1. **Back up your project somewhere**
2. In a terminal go to your project directory and `rm -rf build`
3. do an `svn update`.  At this point Subversion will hopefully restore the build directory.
4. `svn rm build`
5. `svn commit -m "Removed build from version control"`
6. (optional) `svn propedit svn:ignore .`  This will bring up an editor for the svn:ignore property.  Add build on a separate line.  After that subversion won't show you the build directory in `svn status` commands.

Comment: Thanks alot for Your Response . It works for me in this case . great relief...  thanks once again

Comment: i accepted the answer Jeremy P . but i have 1 problem here can u solve that after commit the project now if at all i changed anything its not showing me the M symbol and commitchanes etc.. it simply coming like a local file.. i have edited the project settings dnt knw wht happening here thank you

Comment: That's because build *is* now a local file.  You should never have your build directory under version control.

Comment: ok so there is no problem if I work like this i.e; with out M symbols and disabled commit project etc .. but any how if we want to check with previous versions this way is not good now Jeremy

Comment: in this case i have added 2 files for checking to know whether they are committing or not.sad,they are not committing, those are not adding to project als ,help me out how can we get that add to repository ,M symbols etc .so, when ever we want to commit the project at that time can delete the build .. Help me

Comment: These two files.  Are they in the build directory?  You should not put your own stuff in the build directory.  If they are in the main project directory, you need to `svn add` them so that Subversion knows that you want to keep them under version control.  You can also do that from Xcode, but I find the command line interface to be more reliable.

Comment: i have added them in the classes folder. jst svn add is enough when it can give after svn commit or before svn commit . and did you understand my problem here i want scm to be worked for checked out files that is when ever i added the files it should come with ? marks and add to repository option should be there ,...

Comment: Hi jeremy, Regarding the last step - I'm getting an error:

svn: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found

How do i edit this variables? to what values? I'm very new to XCode..

Comment: @Italy Levin: you need to set one of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR to an editor you can use to enter comments for svn commits.  How you set them and what you set them to depends on the operating system.

Comment: @Italy:  Suggest you ask it as a proper question rather than in the comments of a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try....XCODE->Build->Cleaning All Targets option.That solved my problem !